# Delay load of data for 2 seconds in jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, delay

I'm loading the search results via jQuery ajax in a div container. I would like the results to be shown to the user after a 2 second delay or after the user has entered at least 3 letters/characters in the textbox to search. How would I do this?

jQuery code:

```
$(".bsearch").keydown(function() {
  //create post data
  var postData = { 
    "search" : $(this).val()
  };

  //make the call
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "quotes_in.php",
    data: postData, 
    success: function(response){
      $("#left").html(response);                    
      $("div#smore").hide();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#left').html(response);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if I want the data to be displayed after the user types in the first 3 letters?

Comment: if($('input').val().trim().length > 3) {
      make_ajax_request();
   }

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
function ajax_delay(str){
 setTimeout("str",2000);
}
```

results will be

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "quotes_in.php",
    data: postData, 
    success: function(response){

        ajax_delay($('#left').html(response));
$("div#smore").hide();
    }
  });
```

hope this helps you