# Why the menu is not always displayed with HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

#### I have a static html pages with html,css and js (with no framework).

I want to separate the menu (navbar) in an external html page and load it in all my html pages. I have some css and animation in nav-animation.js that should be loaded after menu is loaded.

So I have my navbar.html file like this :

```html
<nav class="animation">
  ...
  ...
</nav>
```

I have a nav.js script which load the menu and the menu animation :

```js
$(function(){
  $("#custom-nav").load("../navbar.html")
  $.getScript("nav-animation.js")
});
```

In all my html pages, I import JQuery in head tag, it's for $.getScript:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

In body tag, I have a div with custom-nav id :

```html
<div id="custom-nav"></div>
```

And at the end of the body tag, I have nav.js script :

```html
<script src="js/nav.js"></script>
```

The menu is correctly loaded in all my html pages. But sometimes it doesn't show up.

**Menu correctly loaded** with animation (toggle, css,...) :

[Image : Menu correctly loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKLa6.png)

**Menu doesn't show up** but is loaded (I can see when I inspect the html of my page that the nav tag is present in my div) :

[Image : Menu doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDND5.png)

I don't have any errors, in console. But when the menu doesn't show up, I think the nav-animation.js is not correctly loaded.

But why doesn't the menu animation load all the time ? Is there a better way to load the menu ?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Dont know if this helps, but I would start from nav.js file. Put some function in it (that returns console.log) and call it from main page to see if it is loaded correctly. If you have main page, I think you need to reference jQuery only once, not in all html pages. You can then reference nav-animation.js in navbar.html.

Comment: @BorisP I try console.log() in nav.js and it's displayed all the time event if the navbar is not loaded. And yes jQuery is just loaded in index.html (main page). When I comment $.getScript code line and add nav-animation.js in navbar.html, I have this warning : `core.min.js:8 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.` **And the page loading is a little slow.**

Comment: I think that Synchronous XMLHttpRequest isn't a problem here, maybe would just freeze a web page until it loads everything. Maybe you could post more code, I'm blind. Anyway, I had similar problem with loading menu on every page. So I added delay 500ms. I had two ajax loads, one for menu and one for loading posts, after all references were loaded. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497700/delay-load-of-data-for-2-seconds-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: @BorisP Thanks for your answer, the menu works correctly !